# php array_diff check numbers with leading zeros

Tags: php

I have numbers in an array like 0001 upto 6500, There are a few missing numbers, I want to find out what ones are missing however i can't get it to work with the leading zeros.

```
foreach($newFiles as $file) {
    $justNumbers[] = substr("$file",0, 4);
}

$arr2 = range(0001,max($justNumbers)); 
$missing = array_diff($arr2,$justNumbers);
print_r($missing);
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: `$justNumbers[] = intval( substr("$file",0, 4) );`

Comment: `$arr2 = array_map(function ($i) { return sprintf("%04d", $i); }, range(1, max($justNumbers)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop through a range, then match against the file name by string padding:

```
foreach($newFiles as $file) {
    $justNumbers[] = substr("$file",0, 4);
}

foreach(range(1, max($justNumbers)) as $i){
  $padded = str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if( !in_array($padded, $justNumbers) ){
        $missing[] = $padded;
    }
}

print_r($missing);
```

**EDIT**

Just for academic reasons, I think you could still have used `array_diff` to arrive at the same result (i.e. following your original code pattern instead of the second `foreach` loop):

```
$arr2 = range(1, max($justNumbers)); 
$padded_arr2 = array_map( function($i){ return str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); }, $arr2 );
$missing = array_diff($padded_arr2, $justNumbers);
print_r($missing);
```

Comment: @Exoon: I just made an addendum to this answer.